# Updating Excel VBA reference

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets in a workbook Sheet1 and Sheet2.

> Sheet1 Cell A1 contains ='Sheet2'!B2
>
> Sheet2 Cell B2 contains 01/10/2018 and is formatted for dates
>
> Sheet2 Cell B3 contains 01/11/2018 and is formatted for dates

Using VBA, I want to read the contents of Sheet1 Cell A1 and then update its contents to read the next date in the list ie.to become ='Sheet2'!B3

The problem I am having is that when I try to access Sheet1 Cell A1 it returns the value of the date in Sheet2 B2 rather than the contents of A1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thank you.

Comment: Read the `Formula` property, not the `Value` property.

Comment: @Rory Thank you 